# AutoHideSplashScreen in iOS doesn't hide the splashscreen in Phonegap 2.5 with a non-index.html page

Tags: ios, cordova

I can't seem to get the `navigator.splashscreen.hide()` function to consistently work on iOS due to the `deviceready` event not firing, so I'm trying to just automatically hide the splash screen. But even though `AutoHideSplashScreen` is set to `true`, my splash screen never goes away. Is there a weird interaction between external URLs and the splash screen not going away? Or is there some setting I'm missing that sets a timer on how long the screen shows for?

Answer (score 0):

I've have a very similar issue although my 'deviceready' event is firing.

In the PhoneGap documentation under 'Splashscreen' its example is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-x.x.x.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}

</script>
```

Sadly for me the Splashscreen still appears. I thought I'd provide this for you anyway as it may work with your system. I'm still searching for my solution.

Good luck

Comment: I'm actually specifically asking about auto-hiding, though, not dismissing it specifically. Hiding it explicitly actually works for me. :)